# R - missing function in tm.plugin.sentiment

Tags: r, text-mining

R has a sentiment analysis plugin for the text-mining package `tm` called `tm.plugin.sentiment`. I'm trying to use this package but I receive a missing function error when running the `score` function.

```
# Libraries ---------------------------------------------------------------
install.packages("tm")
install.packages("tm.plugin.sentiment", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
require(tm)
require(tm.plugin.sentiment)


# Data --------------------------------------------------------------------
data(crude)
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(crude))

corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)

# Score -------------------------------------------------------------------
score <- score(corpus)
```

when run, this code leads to:

```
score <- score(corpus)
Error in polarity.TermDocumentMatrix(list(i = c(43L, 79L, 102L, 138L,   
         could not find function "tm_tag_score"
```

This sounds like it relates to `tm.plugin.tags` which I believe must be deprecated (?) but I receive no dependency error when installing.

Further more, this page seems to indicate that the missing function should belong to `tm` which is an active package, yet this error occurs with every machine and version of `tm` that I've tried it with.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tm.plugin.sentiment_0.0.1 quantmod_0.4-0           
[3] TTR_0.22-0                xts_0.9-7                
[5] zoo_1.7-11                Defaults_1.1-1           
[7] tm_0.6                    NLP_0.1-3                

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.1.0      lattice_0.20-29 parallel_3.1.0 
[4] slam_0.1-32     SnowballC_0.5.1 tools_3.1.0
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: looks that [this function](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/tm/docs/tm_tag_score) is removed from the recent version of `tm`.

Comment: @Dason Sure I will add that info to the post

Comment: @agstudy Oh, is that what happened? Thanks for the heads up I will see about trying to run an older version of tm. Do you know why it was removed?

Comment: @Hack-R i don't know. It is just a guess. You can contact the package maintainer.

Comment: @agstudy oh, it's just a guess. ok cool. I am checking that possibility now, thanks.

Comment: The [NLPutils](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NLPutils/index.html) package may provide help here with the `QDAP_Polarity_Annotator()
` function.